# Does Laravel have something similar to Drupal Views and Display Suite?

Tags: laravel, drupal-7, drupal-views

I recently taught myself the ins and outs of Drupal, became very familiar with Views and Display Suite, and am considering hiring a small development team to build a Guitar Lessons paid membership site for me in Laravel.

I will be creating the content for the site, and don't want to spend much time messing with the site. I need to focus on guitar playing. So the site needs to let me control my content in an efficient way. I need to be able to create views and choose fields and formatting (e.g. recent lessons, similar lessons, etc), as well as have flexibility in where I place views (on a sidebar, etc).

So, that said, are there plugins for Laravel that will enable me to do this or something similar? I mean I can code PHP and write MySQL queries, but I can't imagine creating/editing views at the PHP/MySQL level every time I want to tweak something.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

In that case you do not need Laravel (why you think of using it?). Stay with Drupal.

If you really need Laravel for some reason, try to use OctoberCMS, which is based on Laravel. Or ask team hired by you to build custon CMS for you.

In Laravel you must code to add or modify views.

Comment: Hi, the reason I am thinking about Laravel is because some developers who knew I was building a site got in touch through a friend and then proposed to do it in Laravel.

Comment: I'd go with some CMS if you don't want to code by yourself anyway. Laravel should be used for bigger projects with non standard features. Using it for things which can be done with any CMS is just a waste of time and money.

Comment: I guess the thing that would be unique about the site is that users will be able to track their progress, bookmark lessons, and there will be some fairly sophisticated role-based control of content.

Comment: @BrianHuether, if my answer was helpful, please choose my answer as best answer and upvote it.